# Django search fields in multiple models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to search multiple fields in many models. I don't want to use other apps like 'Haystack', only pure Django. For example:

```
# models.py

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("First name", max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last name", max_length=255)
    # other fields


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restaurant_name = models.CharField("Restaurant name", max_length=255)
    # other fields


class Pizza(models.Model):
    pizza_name = models.CharField("Pizza name", max_length=255)
    # other fields
```

When I type "Tonny" I should get a:

- "Tonny Montana" from `Person` model
- "Tonny's Restaurant" from `Restaurant` model
- "Tonny's Special Pizza" from `Pizza` model.

Comment: Found this package which could be helpful: https://pypi.org/project/django-querysetsequence/
Only thing to keep in mind, is that it works only if models have same column/field names - thus, you could annotate a `name` field which holds `restauranr_name` in case of `Restaurant` model etc.
Don't know if this makes it easier to read though...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One solution is to query all the models

```
# Look up Q objects for combining different fields in a single query
from django.db.models import Q
people = Person.objects.filter(Q(first_name__contains=query) | Q(last_name__contains=query)
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(restaurant_name__contains=query)
pizzas = Pizza.objects.filter(pizza_name__contains=query)
```

Then combine the results, if you want

```
from itertools import chain
results = chain(people, restaurants, pizzas)
```

---

Ok, sure, here's a more generic solution. Search all CharFields in all models:

```
search_models = [] # Add your models here, in any way you find best.
search_results = []
for model in search_models:
    fields = [x for x in model._meta.fields if isinstance(x, django.db.models.CharField)]
    search_queries = [Q(**{x.name + "__contains" : search_query}) for x in fields]
    q_object = Q()
    for query in search_queries:
        q_object = q_object | query

    results = model.objects.filter(q_object)
    search_results.append(results)
```

This will give you a list of all the querysets, you can then mold it to a format you choose to work with.

To get a list of models to fill `search_models`, you can do it manually, or use something like [`get_models`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_models). Read the docs for more information on how that works.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. This is helpful, but in my project I have 30+ models with multiple fields and I'm wondering is there way to not type filter for every field in models?

Comment: Added a more generic solution.

Comment: It will will display all the data from all the models,  how to use   custom model manager in the generic solutions.

Comment: Just in case anyone else gets stuck on django is not defined:
import:

from django.db.models import Q, CharField

then change django.db.models.CharField in the above code to CharField..

Thanks for this answer, helped me a lot BTW.