# how to search multiple classes in the model

Tags: django, django-models, python-itertools

i have a django project that include **1 model file** consist of  **2 classes**

- class Folder
- class suspect

Note  these 2 classes are not related.

i have a search form that allow user to filter in both classes.

based on the answer of this question  [Django search fields in multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695150/django-search-fields-in-multiple-models)

i used the itertools and import chain

but i did not success in returning the correct result.

update the code based on the answer of @Willem Van Onsem

## views.py

```
class BaseSearchListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result'
    # template_name = 'blog/update2.html'
    template_name = 'blog/list.html'



class FolderListView(BaseSearchListView):
    model = Folder

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(**kwargs).filter(
            FolderNum__icontains= self.request.GET.get('q')
        )
        return render(self.request,"create_folder_test.html",{'search-folder':to_search})

class SuspectListView(BaseSearchListView):
    model = suspect

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return super().get_queryset(**kwargs).filter(
            Q(suspect_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(suspect_father_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(suspect_mother_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) |
            Q(create_date__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()

        #paginator in order to make several pages 
        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10) # Show 5 items per page
        page_request_var = "page"#this line to change dynamicly the string befor the number of page like **page 1** or **abc 1**
        page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
        queryset = paginator.get_page(page)

        context={
            "object_list":queryset,
            "title":"List Items",
            "page_request_var":page_request_var,
        }
        return render(self.request ,"blog/list.html",{'search-suspect':to_search})
```

## header.html

```
<body>

<div class="mynav">
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light ">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
               <li class="nav-item ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="{%  url 'create_folder_test'  %}">MainPage</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this blog">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{% url to_search|default:'search-folder' %}">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="search..." name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}">

                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">

                    </button>

            </form>             
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You need to convert it to a list, an `chain` is lazy, so `result = [*folders, *suspects]` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

A `chain` is a *lazy* iterator. If you print it, you thus print the `chain` object.

In your template, you should *iterate* over the chain object, like:

```
{% for item in result %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

In your view, you can print the list of objects, for example by constructing a list first with:

```
    print([*folders, *suspects])
```

---

**EDIT**

If you only want to show one of the two results, I propse that you make two separate views. Perhaps as a subclass of [**`ListView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview):

```
# app/views.py

from app.models import Folder, Suspect

from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class BaseSearchListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result'
    template_name = 'blog/update2.html'


class FolderListView(BaseSearchListView):
    model = Folder

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(**kwargs).filter(
            FolderNum__icontains= self.request.GET.get('q'))
        )

class SuspectListView(BaseSearchListView):
    model = suspect

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return super().get_queryset(**kwargs).filter(
            Q(suspect_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(suspect_father_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(suspect_mother_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) |
            Q(create_date__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
```

The `urls.py` can then use the two views:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import include, path
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('search_folder/', views.FolderListView.as_view(), name='search-folder'),
    path('search_suspect/', views.SuspectListView.as_view(), name='search-suspect')
]
```

Then you can write a form with:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{% url to_search|default:'search-folder' %}">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Now you can set a variable in the context with which you render the template, to alter the action target. For example if you pass to the context `{'to_search': 'search-suspect'}`, it will thus point to a different view.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply. your answer is returning the result in both classes but if i need to make the user return the requested result based on the template name ??

i mean
 if the user is in the template related to folder i need to filter only the Folder class and return the resul 
else  if the user is in the template related to suspect i need to filter only the suspect class and return the result.

is this possible ??

Comment: @DevDj: then you should make two different views, each with a different filtering mechanism. A path however has nothing to do with the template itself. Several views can render the same template.

Comment: in my project i have the search form in the navigation bar so its included in all templates  what i think if its possible to return the result of the search based on the template .

i will add the search form in order to explain my question better.

Comment: @DevDj: then you should change the "action" url of the form, depending on what page you render. You can do so by providing the url to the context, and use  a default if not present.

Comment: this is exactly what i am searching for how to change  the action url  depending on the page

Comment: @DevDj: see edit for the basic idea for a parameterized action url.

Comment: @ WillemVanOnsem sorry for the late reply  but it always take the default url that i wrote in the action ===> `action="{% url to_search|default:'search-suspect' %}"` 
with no change based on the rendered page

Comment: @DevDj: as said, you should pass to the context of that rendered page `'search-folder'` as `to_search` variable, you thus will need to slightly alter the pages where you want the search to search the folders instead of the `Suspect`s.

Comment: i still not able to understand how to send the context  because it still not changing the action url  i will edit my question and add the updated code based on your answer.

Comment: @DevDj: not the context of the search result page, the context of the pages with the search bar where you wish to alter the search target...

Comment: sorry but i am confused about **the context  of the pages with search bar**

i don't know if i explain my problem right.

i have a search form 
2 templates 
 where user will search  for 2 classes based on what is the current active template.

i know that your answer is close for what i want but i don't know how to continue in order to send the context .