# how to search a slug in different table and add the item to orderItem table one-to-many field Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to add different product table in **OrderItem** item field using **ForeignKey**,
in this time **slug** only search in one table gamingpc and add only the gamingpc in **OrderItem** item field, it should search all of my product tables, and add the product to the **OrderItem** model using **ForeignKey**.

**models.py**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        gamingpc, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        PcComponent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = request.data.get('slug')
    variations = request.data.get('variations', [])
    if slug is None:
        return Response({"message": "Invalid request"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    item = get_object_or_404(gamingpc, slug=slug)
```

Comment: Please provide some more information so that we can help you.

Comment: I  add some more info,if you need anything more please let me know. i have been stuck for 5 days

Comment: Hello @RitwikShaw so what actually you want

Comment: from slug you have to get your **gamingpc** object and than you have to grab your product using same slug am I correct?

Comment: assume i have different product table cpu, gpu, ram.how can i search the slug from all of my products table.and grab the specific product and add to the orderItem model item field

Comment: Okay so you have to search multiple model at onetime

Comment: Does this answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695150/django-search-fields-in-multiple-models

Comment: YES, it's worked. but how to add the result product in orderItem model item field. using foreign key

Answer (score 0):

change your model to :

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
            user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            content_object = GenericForeignKey()
            object_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
            content_type = models.ForeignKey(
                ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                limit_choices_to=(models.Q(model__in=['PcComponent', 'gamingpc']))
```

and for view :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = request.data.get('slug')
    variations = request.data.get('variations', [])
    if slug is None:
        return Response({"message": "Invalid request"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    item = get_object_or_404(gamingpc, slug=slug)
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(user=request.user, object_id=item.pk, content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='gamingpc'))
    ...
    ...
```